# IVR auto dial send DTMF tones in an interval programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call, ivr, dtmf, android-dialer

I need to make an **IVR -auto dialer** application, which

=> dials a toll-free number

=> then selects an option to continue

=> then input some code

=> then after some seconds (some advertisements/ say 30 sec.) need to enter another option

the first three things resolved, as there is not having much waiting time!

I have implemented this like below:

```
String dialnumber = tollfree+","+option1+","+code; //eg: 1800,2,12345    
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+dialnumber));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
```

this is successful to reach till the option, after this, there is a waiting time....
i tried by putting ";" (semi-colon) before appending the last string with dialnumber. but it is not working

```
String dialnumber = tollfree+","+option1+","+code+";"+lastoption; //eg: 1800,2,12345;98765
```

the dialer exits when i start call, but if I remove the last option, then it works

my question is: **how can i put the last option to dialer after an interval** of 30secs. ?

I heard that we cannot interfere with the default dialer while on  active call.

Answer (score 2):

There is one for Mobile / PSTN phone network [Meeting Auto Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technochakra.meetingautodialer).But not for VoIP network.

I am also looking for VoIP network, I could not find any for Android , there is one opensource implementation, [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org), for which the implementation is open for contribution.
[PRE-DIAL DTMF TONES](https://jitsi.org/GSOC/PredialDTMF)